# Doctests to check the radius, area and circumference of a circle using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, doctest

I have written the below mentioned code but got the following error:

> "ValueError: line 2 of the docstring for **main**.Circle.circumference lacks blank after >>>: '        >>>c1 = Circle(2.5)'.

Please tell me how to resolve this error?

class Circle:

```
def __init__(self, radius):
    """
    >>> c1 = Circle(2.5)
    >>> c1.radius
    2.5
    """
    self.radius = radius

def area(self):
    """
    >>> c1 = Circle(2.5)
    >>> c1.area()
    19.63
    """
    a = math.pi * self.radius * self.radius
    return round(a,2)


def circumference(self):
    """
    >>>c1 = Circle(2.5)
    >>>c1.circumference()
    15.71
    """
    c = 2 * math.pi * self.radius
    return round(c,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code misses the space after the >>> in circumference on these lines:

```
    >>>c1 = Circle(2.5)
    >>>c1.circumference()
```

Comment: Use this:
>>> c1 = Circle(2.5)
>>> c1.circumference()

Answer (score 0):

Use this code as reference you may get answer...

class Circle:

```
def __init__(self, radius):

    """
    >>> c1 = Circle(2.5)
    >>> c1.radius
    2.5
    """
    self.radius = radius

def area(self):

    """
    >>> c1 = Circle(2.5)
    >>> c1.area()
    19.63

    """

    return round(math.pi*(self.radius**2),2)
def circumference(self):
    """
    >>> c1=Circle(2.5)
    >>> c1.circumference()
    15.71

    """

    return round(math.pi*(self.radius*2),2)
```